# Center image gallery placeholder

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with centering the image placeholder of my gallery when I click for full size view on a thumbnail. Basically what's happening - it centers , but the second time when I click on the same thumbnail for full size view. The first time when I click the thumbnail for full size view the placeholder is not centered and the second time when I click on the same thumbnail the placeholder is centered. The placeholder is absolutely positioned width 50% to the left and I calculate the size of the next image with jquery in order to give it negative margin to the left and center it. It seems that the first time when the thumbnail is clicked , the script is not taking the size of the upcoming image, but the second time when click on the same thumbnail it does the job and centers the placeholder.

```js
$('.view-full-size').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentImage = $(this).attr('href').replace('img/fullsize-', '')
        .replace('.jpg', '');
    var newPlaceholder = $('.full-size-img figure > img').attr('src', 'img/fullsize-' + currentImage + '.jpg');
    $('.full-size-img').each(function () {
        var imageWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var newWidth = -(imageWidth / 2);
        $(this).css('margin-left', newWidth + 'px');
    });
});

// SLIDER IMAGES
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var currentImage = parseInt($('.full-size-img figure > img').attr('src').replace('img/fullsize-', '')
        .replace('.jpg', ''));
    currentImage = currentImage + 1;
    var nextSrc = $('.full-size-img figure > img').attr('src', 'img/fullsize-' + currentImage + '.jpg').fadeIn();
});

$('#previous').on('click', function () {
    var currentImage = parseInt($('.full-size-img figure > img').attr('src').replace('img/fullsize-', '')
        .replace('.jpg', ''));
    currentImage = currentImage - 1;
    var nextSrc = $('.full-size-img figure > img').attr('src', 'img/fullsize-' + currentImage + '.jpg');
});
```

```css
.full-size-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
}

.full-size-img figure {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.full-size-img figure img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 90vh;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery" class="gallery-section section-tab">
  <div class="thumbnails cf">
    <figure>
      <a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-26.jpg">
        <img src="img/sample-image-thumb26.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <figcaption><a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-26">full size</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-27.jpg">
        <img src="img/sample-image-thumb27.jpg" alt=""><a/>
        <figcaption><a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-27">full size</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-28.jpg">
        <img src="img/sample-image-thumb28.jpg" alt=""><a/>
        <figcaption><a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-28">full size</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-29.jpg">
        <img src="img/sample-image-thumb29.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <figcaption><a class="view-full-size" href="img/fullsize-29">full size</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <!-- end thumbnails -->

</div>
<!-- end gallery-section -->


<!-- SINGLE IMAGE -->
<div class="full-size-img">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/fullsize-1.jpg" alt="" />
    <!-- <figcaption>
         <span class="full-img-close"><img src="img/close-gallery-btn.png" alt="close button"/></span>
        </figcaption> -->
    <span id="previous">previous</span>
    <span id="next">next</span>
  </figure>
</div>
<!-- end full size image -->
```

Comment: your code snippet is not working.

Comment: I noticed this when I was editing your question for readability. There are several `HTML` markup errors in your code. I could have fixed them and make the snippet work, but I thought it's more important that I inform you about them so you fix them in your project. Here is your ["fixed" html](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5ozusx7s/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with **display: none;**.

```
$('.full-size-img').each(function(){
            var imageWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
            var newWidth = -(imageWidth / 2);
            $(this).css('margin-left',newWidth + 'px');
        });
```

On the first click, you populate the new image and **.full-size-img** doesn't have access to **var imageWidth = $(this).outerWidth();**  until **fadeIn()** is called and its display property is set to block.

Only on the second click will you have access to the box properties, since the first click made the element take a physical form in the viewport.

Rather than using **display: none;** you should try using **visibility & opacity

- List item

**:

```
.full-size-img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:200;
    top:5%;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    /*display:none;*/
    visibility: hidden;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE 5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* Netscape */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; /* Safari 1.x */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Good browsers */
}
```

Although, off the top of my head, visibility may cause another issue with the fade function, but I'll leave that up to you to dabble in. Maybe set visibility: visible on click and let fade handle opacity...